# What is the best way to retrieve specific elements from an HTML page in VBA?

Tags: html, excel, vba, xmlhttprequest

I have an Excel sheet with some URLs and I'm trying to write a macro that populates categories of websites using Fortigate's web filter. So for example, a cell on the sheet might contain "www.google.com" and the site categorizes it as "Search Engines and Portals" at the URL https://fortiguard.com/webfilter?q=google.com.

I'm having a hard time trying to parse the HTML to get the category. The HTML looks like:

```
<DIV class=sidebar-content>
<H4>WF Rating History</H4>
<P><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 10px"><EM>Jun 10th, 2008 @ 17:45:24 PDT</EM></SPAN><BR>added as <STRONG>Search Engines and Portals</STRONG></P>
<DIV><A href="about://forticlient.com/" target=_blank><IMG src="about:/static/images/forticlient_share_button.png?v=5"></A> </DIV></DIV>
```

and the code I used to get that is below (I'm just trying with one site and have made the assumption that it is located on A1 on the sheet):

```
    Sub siteCatgories()

    Dim xhr As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    Set xhr = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

    Url = Cells(1, 1).Value

    With xhr
    .Open "GET", "https://fortiguard.com/webfilter?q=" & Url, False
    .send

    If .readyState = 4 And .Status = 200 Then
        Set doc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
        doc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End If
    End With

    'retrieve relevant HTML
    Debug.Print doc.getElementsByClassName("sidebar-content").toString

    End Sub
```

The above debug statement only returns [Object]. 
Any help on how to parse the site's HTML in VBA would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What exactly you want to extract from the webpage.? which fields you want to extract?

Comment: `Debug.Print doc.getElementsByClassName("sidebar-content")(0).toString` (*getElementsByClassName* is plural; i.e. a collection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such simple parsing could be done using `Split()` instead of `HTMLDocument`:

```vb
Sub Test()

    MsgBox Join(GetData("google.com"), vbCrLf)

End Sub

Function GetData(sUrl)

    Dim tmp

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://fortiguard.com/webfilter?q=" & sUrl, False, "u051772", "fy17janr"
        .Send
        tmp = .ResponseText
    End With
    tmp = Split(tmp, "WF Rating History", 2)(1)
    tmp = Split(tmp, "<em>", 2)(1)
    tmp = Split(tmp, "</strong>", 2)(0)
    tmp = Split(tmp, "</em>", 2)
    tmp(1) = Split(tmp(1), "<strong>", 2)(1)
    GetData = tmp

End Function
```

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: I guess my worry, through lack of experience, is how robust this method is?
 Would you determine the appropriateness of this on the basis of how "stable" the webpage layout is i.e. on your impression of its consistency in layout/format over time? Any references I could read on how to decide which method to use when scraping? Btw I upvoted as useful but am intrigued.

Answer (score 0):

How about giving this a try:

```
Sub Fetch_Data()
    Dim http As New ServerXMLHTTP60, HTML As New HTMLDocument
    Dim post As Object

    With http
        .Open "GET", "https://fortiguard.com/webfilter?q=google.com", False
        .send
        HTML.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    For Each post In HTML.getElementsByClassName("sidebar-content")
        With post.getElementsByTagName("em")
            If .Length Then Row = Row + 1: Cells(Row, 1) = .Item(0).innerText
        End With
        With post.getElementsByTagName("strong")
            If .Length Then Cells(Row, 2) = .Item(0).innerText
        End With
    Next post
End Sub
```

Output:

```
Jun 10th, 2008 @ 17:45:24 PDT
Search Engines and Portals
```

Reference to add to the library:

```
1.Microsoft Html Object Library
2.Microsoft XML, V6.0
```